# How to I create a view in Oracle where I can pass a parameter to it?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I created a view in Oracle

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER
ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID
```

This works fine I can run select * from MyView.

How can I create a new view where I would pass a parameter to it?

Ex (Pseudo Code):

```
@LastName = 'Smith';
    SELECT *
    FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE LAST_NAME = @LastName
    ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID
```

Comment: Why do you need a view for that?

Comment: This is a simple sample for a more complex issue that I have.

Comment: Instead of a view what would you recommend?

Comment: Just a normal select query.

Comment: Just make sure the columns you want to filter on are in your view definition, then your view can be simple and you don't need complicated view parameters.

Answer (score 4):

You can't pass a parameter to a view.

Normally, it is enough to query a view and to let the optimizer handle pushing the predicate into the most appropriate place

```
create view customer_view
as
select *
  from customer

select *
  from customer_view
 where last_name = :lastName
 order by customer_id
```

You can write your view so that it references a value that is set in a package variable.  That's a bit of a hack but it comes close to passing a parameter to a view

```
create or replace package my_pkg
as
  g_last_name customer.last_name%type;

  function get_last_name
    return customer.last_name%type;

  procedure set_last_name( p_last_name in customer.last_name%type );
end my_pkg;

create or replace package body my_pkg
as
  procedure set_last_name( p_last_name in customer.last_name%type )
  as
  begin
    g_last_name := p_last_name;
  end;

  function get_last_name
    return customer.last_name%type
  is
  begin
    return g_last_name;
  end;
end;

create or replace view customer_view
as
select *
  from customer
 where last_name = my_pkg.get_last_name;

exec my_pkg.set_last_name( 'Smith' );
select *
  from customer_view
 order by customer_id;
```

Or you could define a pipelined table function that accepts a parameter and can be queried like a table

```
create type customer_obj
    as object (
  customer_id integer,
  first_name  varchar2(100),
  last_name   varchar2(100)
);

create type customer_nt
    as table of customer_obj;

create or replace function my_pipeline_function( p_last_name in customer.last_name%type )
  return customer_nt
  pipelined
is
begin
  for c in (select customer_obj( customer_id, first_name, last_name ) customer
              from customer
             where last_name = p_last_name)
  loop
    pipe row( c.customer );
  end loop;
end;

select *
  from table( my_pipeline_function( 'Smith' ))
 order by customer_id;
```

If you join this pipelined table function to some other table, however, be aware that Oracle will not be able to push any predicates into the pipelined table function's query or perform other transforms.  And the optimizer often has a hard time guessing how many rows a particular pipeline table function call will return which can cause it to choose less than optimal plans without some work.  That can make it challenging to optimize queries that rely on a bunch of pipeline table functions.

Comment: OK.  I will need to get for reporting purposes.  This data will need to be based off parameters most likely a date or date range.  I am trying to understand the best way (view, stored proc) to get this data.  Whatever the preferred way I need to be able to read this view/sp whatever in Entity Framework. (I know getting off topic)  The architect mentioned view so I just started down that path. If there is a easier way then I would like to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

If you can review this point of view with your architect! so, I suggest you to create a stored proc with an OUT parameter. This parameter will be a REF CURSOR. The SP would be something like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE yourSP (v_DataReturned OUT ref cursor, -- Data will be returned to your report.
                        v_last_name customer.last_name%type -- parameter used in the WHERE clause) 

IS 
BEGIN
   OPEN v_DataReturned FOR
   SELECT * FROM customer t  -- replace* by fields you need to have
   WHERE t.last_name = v_last_name;
END;
```

So, if you want to verify values returned by the procedure yourSP, you can execute this script on SQL Developer or SQL*Plus :

```
 variable rc_returned ref cursor;
 execute yourSP(:rc_returned,'John' -- or another last_name);
 print rc_returned;
```